# What should I do with amulet of Talos?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Greta asked me to take it from catacomb. After that I return to her. I suppose I gave that thing to her. The problem is it's still in my hand. It's marked as stolen. Thus, anytime I get caught it will be gone. What should I do with it? I want to check whether I really have completed "Return to Grace" quest, because I'm not finding the quest in my journal.

Comment: I am supposed to give that amulet. Turns out I finished the quest and the amulet is still in my hand. Also it's marked stolen. So what do people usually do with it.

Answer (score 7):

[This quest](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace) has multiple bugs.

To complete it, all you have to do is return the amulet to Greta.

If you've done that, and it's not complete, you've probably encountered one or both of these bugs, taken from the linked wiki page's [Bugs section](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Return_to_Grace#Bugs):

> - If Roggvir's Amulet of Talos is taken before this quest, any Amulet of Talos picked up after that will be marked as a quest item and cannot be dropped or sold.
> - This quest may stay in the miscellaneous quest section even after completion.

The reward for completing the quest is just a leveled pile of gold, so it's not something to really worry about, even if having it in your quest list is ugly and bothersome.

Comment: Thank you for being the only one to actually supply a link that is directly related to OP's question, and not just a google search or the general Skyrim wiki.

Answer (score -1):

That quest has several bugs, you should install the [Unofficial Skyrim Legendary Edition Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/?) which fixes most of the issues people may encounter with the game.

In doubt always consult http://uesp.net, it contains everything you ever want to know about The Elder Scrolls games and lore.